# How can I stop moving vehicles without having to chase it down?

Tags: far-cry-5

There are many opportunities to want to shoot up vehicles you come across. But it's always painful to reap the rewards of doing so. What usually happens is:

1. Target is spotted
2. I get into position to attack ahead of the vehicle
3. I kill the driver
4. The vehicle continues to coast ahead right past me
5. It stops at a tree or embankment far away
6. I run over to it
7. Score

Is there a more effective way to do this?

Comment: I saw a special weapon in the store that does 0 damage. I was assuming it was an EMP weapon that disables vehicles. It requires a specific quest to unlock. It looks like the radiation gun from Fallout.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I think you are referring to the Magnopulser. Which is some alien gun that you can unlock by completing a series of side quests. It typically pushes anything away when fired similar to a gravity gun. I am not sure if that would stop a moving car or launch it away, but it's worth a try.

Comment: @FlamingThunder I actually meant to delete that comment. I realized that the gun didn't do what I thought it did.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Well it might work just not the way you expected it to.

Comment: @FlamingThunder Considering I read that it vaporizes its target though, I don't know if I'd trust it for vehicles like prisoner vans.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yeah that's why I said "typically pushes" its targets away because it vaporizes them if you get really close, but I have seen it used on vehicles and they never got vaporized unlike enemies and wild animals. Still it needs to be tested first because I haven't seen someone use it on a moving car or van so I'm not sure what would happen.

Answer (score 3):

I've found that the best way to get anything done easily in Far Cry 5 is to use one of the helicopters with mounted 50cal guns.  It takes a bit of getting used to, but you can very accurately target anything and they are extremely powerful weapons.  Plus you don't need to run anywhere, you can just fly!

With this method, you can decide whether to completely destroy any vehicle (very quickly and easily) or retrieve it to use yourself.  If you find a vehicle that you would like to drive/salvage, simply kill the driver and either fly to where it stops, or shoot at it's tires and it should slow the vehicle down for you.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The best way I've found is a secondary grenade launcher shot at the front of the vehicle. It blows the tires, and disables the engine.

This tends to cause the vehicle to stop immediately, and doesn't kill hostages*.

Of course this won't work if you want to salvage the vehicle, and don't have a repair torch. This also won't necessarily work if you have the perk that deals extra damage to vehicles. It might just cause vehicles to immediately explode. I don't have the perk, so I haven't tested it in that scenario.

---

`*` When I posted this answer, I hadn't killed any hostages using this method. After using it like a hundred times now though, I did once accidentally blow up a hostage van, killing the hostages. The van blew up as soon as the grenade hit it, so it must have been in a fight before it got to me.

Comment: Do you by any chance have the perk that deals extra damage to vehicles?

Comment: @JeffMercado No. That might invalidate this. I'll add something. Thanks for thinking of that.